# CMMotionActivityManager startActivityUpdates keep detects user activity after calling stopActivityUpdates()

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

Am developing an app to get the user activity using CMMotionActivity. It is working fine. I also get the user activities in the following method.

```
CMMotionActivityManager *activityManager = [[CMMotionActivityManager alloc] init];

[activityManager startActivityUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] withHandler:
    ^(CMMotionActivity *activity) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        });
    }
];
```

But the issue is that, when i call the following method

```
[activityManager stopActivityUpdates];
```

it will not stop detecting the user activity. It is still working. Can you  tell me that why it is happen?

**Updated Question**

I called start activity update by calling the following method.

```
 -(void)StartUserActivityUpdates 
{
    if ([CMMotionActivityManager isActivityAvailable]) {
    activityManager = [[CMMotionActivityManager alloc] init];
    [activityManager startActivityUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                     withHandler:
     ^(CMMotionActivity *activity) {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         });
      }];
}}
```

I stop the activity update by calling following method.

```
 -(void)StopActivityUpdates 
 {
    activityManager = [[CMMotionActivityManager alloc] init];
    [activityManager stopActivityUpdates];
 }
```

Comment: Need a little more information. Can you post larger snippets? Where do you call `startActivityUpdatesToQueue`, where you call `stopActivityUpdates`?

Comment: Do you have two `activityManager` variables? A local one where you create `CMMotionActivityManager` and a property/ivar used when calling `stopActivityUpdates`?

Comment: @ rmaddy 
No, i have using a global variable. I put the local variable in my code why because of clarify the question.

Comment: @ mag_zbc
i called it in the NSObject class. I updated the question the relevant codes, please check it.