# Calling stopActivityUpdates is not stopping updates

Tags: swift

After staring motionActivityUpdates, any attempt to stop it is not working. Here is the code that I am using for starting the motionactivity. There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136419/cmmotionactivitymanager-startactivityupdates-keep-detects-user-activity-after-ca) without any answers and it is in C. Reading the documentation this is supposed to stop activity updates

> Call this method to stop the delivery of updates that you started by calling the startActivityUpdates(to:withHandler:) method. This method does not stop queries started using the queryActivityStarting(from:to:to:withHandler:) method.

```
var manager: CMMotionActivityManager?
var motionManager: CMMotionManager?
func startMotionMonitoring() {
    motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    manager = CMMotionActivityManager()
    startActivityMonitoring()
}

func startActivityMonitoring() {
    if !CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() {
        return
    }

    if CMMotionActivityManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorized {
        return
    }

    if let man = manager {
        man.startActivityUpdates(to: .main) { (activity) in
            guard let a = activity else {
                return
            }
            print("motionActive")
        }
    }
}
```

I have another function I call to stop everything

```
func endMotionMonitoring(){
    if manager == nil && motionManager == nil { return }
    manager!.stopActivityUpdates()
    manager = nil

    motionManager!.stopAccelerometerUpdates()
    motionManager = nil
}
```

But it is not stopping the motion activity updates. Every time I move the phone it prints out the statement "motionActive"

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Does it reach `manager!.stopActivityUpdates()` line? When `endMotionMonitoring()` func is called? Is it getting called at all?

Comment: It does reach manager!.stopActivityUpdates(). Putting a print statement and stepping through the code both times it hits.